# Munit mocking DB connector

Tags: java, mule, munit

I'm trying to write an integration test for a mule flow that retrieves a file from a JMS queue and inserts it into a DB. One test scenario is running through the exception flow when the DB is not available (connection error). For this test I want to mock the DB connector and let it throw an exception.

I tried to mock the connector like this:

```
@Test
public void testDBOutageException() throws Exception {
    MuleEvent event = testEvent(INPUT_VALID_XML);

    java.net.ConnectException connectException = new java.net.ConnectException("Could not connect to DB!");     
    MessageProcessorMocker dbMocker = whenMessageProcessor("insert").ofNamespace("db");     
    dbMocker.thenThrow(connectException);

    event = runFlow("thomson-reuters-processFlow", event);
}
```

When running the test case above the flow is called successfully but the DB connector is not mocked. It just makes it's call to the DB and inserts data. This is not what I want to achieve.

My flow looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:thomson-reuters-process.properties, classpath:thomson-reuters-process-${env}.properties"></context:property-placeholder>

  <spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <spring:property name="url" value="${JDBC.url}"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="username" value="${JDBC.username}"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="password" value="${JDBC.password}"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="${JDBC.driver}"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="initialSize" value="5"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="validationQuery" value="${JDBC.validationQuery}"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="maxWait" value="60000"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="maxActive" value="50"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300"></spring:property>
      <spring:property name="logAbandoned" value="true"></spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
  </spring:beans>

  <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" username="${JMS.User}" password="${JMS.Password}" brokerURL="tcp://${JMS.Host}:${JMS.Port}" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ">
    <reconnect frequency="10000" count="10" />
  </jms:activemq-connector>
  <!-- <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="MySQL Configuration" 
        database="${DB.Database}" host="${DB.Host}" password="${DB.Password}" port="${DB.Port}" 
        user="${DB.User}"></db:mysql-config> -->
  <db:generic-config name="DB_Config" dataSource-ref="dataSource" doc:name="DB_Config" />
  <flow name="thomson-reuters-processFlow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${JMS.InQueue}" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="Retrieve from ActiveMQ JMS"></jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <set-variable variableName="inboundPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Store inboundPayload"></set-variable>
    <!-- <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger> <mulexml:schema-validation-filter 
            schemaLocations="test-XSD-schema.xsd" returnResult="true" doc:name="Schema 
            Validation"></mulexml:schema-validation-filter> <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger> -->
    <logger message="LOGGER 1: Inbound file from JMS, payload is: #[message.payloadAs(String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
    <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/Report/Data/Row[position()&gt;1]',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="Split XML to currency dataset"></splitter>
    <logger message="LOGGER 2: XML was split to forex data set" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"></mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer>
    <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Build collection of individual currency rates">
      <expression-message-info-mapping messageIdExpression="#[message.id]" correlationIdExpression="#[message.correlationId]" />
    </collection-aggregator>
    <logger message="LOGGER 3: Combined forex data in collection" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
    <db:insert config-ref="DB_Config" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Push xml collection to DB" doc:description="dbConnectorInsert">
      <db:dynamic-query>
        <![CDATA[INSERT INTO `exchange_rates`(`CURRENCY`, `DATE`, `REF_CURRENCY`, `EXCHANGE_RATE`,`CREATED_BY`,`CREATE_DATE`,`CHANGED_BY`,`CHANGE_DATE`,`BUYING_RATE`,`SPECIAL_RATE`) VALUES ('#[xpath3('//CURRENCY')]','#[xpath3('//DATE')]','#[xpath3('//REF_CURRENCY')]','#[xpath3('//EXCHANGE_RATE')]','${System.User}','#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')]', '${System.User}','#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')]','#[xpath3('//BUYING_RATE')]','#[xpath3('//SELLING_RATE')]');]]>
      </db:dynamic-query>
    </db:insert>
    <logger message="LOGGER 4: DB Processing completed, payload is: #[message.payloadAs(String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="thomson-reuters-processCatch_Exception_Strategy">
      <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
      <set-payload value="#[flowVars.inboundPayload]" doc:name="Set Original Inbound Payload"></set-payload>
      <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Remove MULE_CORRELATION_ID">
        <delete-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
      </message-properties-transformer>
      <logger message="Exception occured, trying to push message to DLQ, payload is: #[message.payloadAs(String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
      <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="${JMS.DLQ}" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="Place on DLQ"></jms:outbound-endpoint>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
  </flow>
</mule>
```

Any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in MUnit 1.1.0 where DB Mock was not working. It has been fixed in MUnit 1.2.0 version which is released recently, try 1.2.0. What version of MUnit are you using?

Comment: I'm using MUnit version 3.6.0-RC2

`<properties>
    <munit.version>3.6.0-RC2</munit.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-common</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>`

Comment: There is no such version for munit. Check this  - https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.2.0/munit-maven-support.

Comment: 3.6.2-RC2 is a really old version of MUnit, pre GA and it's not being supported. 
I would advise you to migrate to a newer version of MUnit (if possible to the last released one).
There's a migration guide for people coming from those old MUnit version, you may want to take a look at it: 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.0.0/munit-1.0.0-migration-guide